# Having issue with start and end date validation

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This is my code..

```
<html>
  <script src='jquery-1.3.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='jquery-ui-1.7.3.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function(selected) { 
          $("#endDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#endDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function(selected) { 
          $("#startDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input type='text' name='startDate' id='startDate' />
<input type='text' name='endDate' id='endDate' />

</html>
```

Once I select the starting data as 04/11/2013, the endDate datepicker allow to select the dates greater than "10/20/2018" i mean october 20 2018. I am not sure what is the issue.  I even tried to replaced the selected with some static date, but i didn't help me.

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using latest jquery version

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried with jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom and its works fine.

Comment: Welcome.All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
$('#startDate').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker(
{
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: ChangeEndDate
});

function ChangeEndDate()
{
    var d = $("#startDate").datepicker('getDate');
    $('#endDate').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker(
    {
        minDate: d,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: firstOfNextMonth
    });
}
```